# PreAuthentication with Spring Security -> Based on URL parameters

Tags: url, authentication, spring-security

The customer want to have the following scenario:

Customer hands out link (webapp address) with 2 parameters to the webapp user. Based on these variables the user will take on specific roles in the webapp.
I don't want any authorization in it. There should only be the authentication check which looks at these url parameters and checks if they are valid and will connect the user to the appropriate role.

How can I realize this?! Is there already a solution available?

Thanks!

regards Matthias

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I already solved the problem.
For those who are interested ....

web.xml

```xml
<!-- ===== SPRING CONFIG ===== -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

applicationContext.xml

```xml
<context:component-scan base-package="at.beko.rainstar2" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```xml
<!-- Configuring security not finished!! -->
<http create-session="never" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
    entry-point-ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/authError.xhtml" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
    <session-management session-fixation-protection="none" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl"
    class="at.beko.rainstar2.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="at.beko.rainstar2.model.LinkForbiddenEntryPoint" />

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
        ref="userDetailsServiceImpl" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthFilter"
    class="at.beko.rainstar2.service.filter.UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="appControlAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="appControlAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

LinkForbiddenEntryPoint.java

```java
public class LinkForbiddenEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    httpResponse.sendRedirect("/rainstar2-webapp/authError.xhtml");
}
```

}

UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter.java

```java
public class UrlParametersAuthenticationFilter extends
    AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request.getParameterMap().size() == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String[] credentials = new String[2];
    credentials[0] = request.getParameter("param1");
    credentials[1] = request.getParameter("param2");
    return credentials;
}
```

}

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements
    AuthenticationUserDetailsService<Authentication> {

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication token)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserDetails userDetails = null;

            String[] credentials = (String[]) token.getPrincipal();
    boolean principal = Boolean.valueOf(token.getCredentials().toString());

    if (credentials != null && principal == true) {
        String name = credentials[0];
        if ("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            userDetails = getAdminUser(name);
        } else if ("händler".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            userDetails = getRetailerUser(name);
        } else if ("user".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            userDetails = getUserUser(name);
        }
    }

    if (userDetails == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not load user : "
                + token.getName());
    }

    return userDetails;
}

private UserDetails getAdminUser(String username) {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
    grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_RETAILER"));
    grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    return new User(username, "notused", true, true, true, true,
            grantedAuthorities);
}

private UserDetails getRetailerUser(String username) {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
    grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_RETAILER"));
    return new User(username, "notused", true, true, true, true,
            grantedAuthorities);
}

private UserDetails getUserUser(String username) {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
    return new User(username, "notused", true, true, true, true,
            grantedAuthorities);
}
```

}

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution but I am getting true in UserDetailsServiceImpl class at String[] credentials = (String[]) token.getPrincipal(); Instated i should get the credentials.

Comment: This related article helped me to implement thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478589/springsecurity-custom-automatic-authentication

Answer (score 2):

The way I have resolved this with similar situations is to to use a servlet filter to grab the parameters.  I would recommend extending the org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.

From these parameters, create an auth object of some sort (such as a token), that can be passed into the AuthenticationManager which you can autowire in (or get in some other method).

You will then need to have an AuthenticationProvider that can handle your auth object and generate a UserDetails object with the GrantedAuthority collection you need to satisfy the specific roles you want the user to have.