# Login via pre authentication filter or form login in spring security

Tags: authentication, spring-security, pre-authentication

I am looking for a way where you can have two ways to get access to my website.

1) You should be able to use form-login and get your authorities and use the website.

2) You should be able to login into another website and there you should be able to press a link with a token and be logged in to my website. (I control both websites and they use the same database)

Stage 1 is completed and works well and I have made stage 2 something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9919988/1915913 and that is working as well, I get a token and I am able to verify it and login.

But my problem is, how can I make them both work for me at the same time, for the same resources. I am pretty sure I know what the problem is, I create a custom filter and i try to use the form-login filter.
That does not work, but can it? Or is there some other way i can get this functionality?

This does not work in a way that the pre-auth filter seems to take over and i cant get the normal login to work and it seems to call the pre-auth filter everytime i go to a new page in the project.

The classes I use for this are all pretty simple.

My security-app-context:

```
<http pattern="/**" use-expressions="true" create-session="always">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
        <custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" />
        <form-login
                username-parameter="idnumber"
                password-parameter="password" login-processing-url="/processlogin"
                login-page='/login.jsp'
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="myAuthErrorHandler"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
                always-use-default-target='true'
                authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=true"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout/" logout-success-url="/login.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/">
            <concurrency-control expired-url="/" max-sessions="2" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <!-- form login -->
    <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="is.inna.rest.login.SuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="myAuthErrorHandler" class="is.inna.rest.login.AuthentificationListener"/>
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
    <beans:bean name="myUserDetailsService" class="is.inna.rest.login.LoginUserDetailService" />

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
        <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

     <!-- Pre auth -->
    <beans:bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"  class="is.inna.rest.login.AuthUserDetailService" />
    <beans:bean id="preauthAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="userDetailsServiceWrapper"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter" class="is.inna.rest.login.PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>
```

My user details services

```
public class AuthUserDetailService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<Authentication> {

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication authentication) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    String id = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
    NotandiHelper notandi = UserDAO.getNotandiByToken(id);

    return new User(notandi.getUsername(), notandi.getPassword(), notandi.getAuthorities());
}
```

}

My pre auth filter

```
 public class PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(request.getParameter("id") != null){
        return request.getParameter("id");
    }else if(request.getParameter("idnumber") != null){
        return request.getParameter("idnumber");
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(request.getParameter("kt") != null){
        String[] credentials = new String[2];
        credentials[0] = request.getParameter("token");
        credentials[2] = request.getParameter("id");
        return credentials;
    }
    if(request.getParameter("idnumber")!= null){
        String[] credentials = new String[2];
        credentials[0] = request.getParameter("idnumber");
        credentials[1] = request.getParameter("password");
        return credentials;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: It should be possible to use them together. You'll need to provide some more information, and explain what you mean when you say "it doesn't work".

Comment: Of course, sorry, I edited. This does not work in a way that the pre-auth filter seems to take over and i cant get the normal login to work and it seems to call the pre-auth filter everytime i go to a new page in the project.

Answer (score 1):

When you're extending a class, you really need to understand how the base class works (one of the problems with inheritance). In this case, you are returning "false" in the case where there is no token present, which is an arbitrary choice for a method returning an object. If you look at the base class, [you will see that it checks for a non-null principal](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java#L106) and returns immediately from `doAuthenticate` if the value is null, causing the filter chain to proceed immediately, as if the pre-authentication filter wasn't there at all. So that's not right. Try returning null instead.

Note that the debug log should also contain a log message saying

> preAuthenticatedPrincipal = null, trying to authenticate

It's also unclear from your configuration how you authenticate the token. There doesn't seem to be anything there to do that.

Note that you'll need to use the entry point for form-login if you want the login form to be displayed automatically for unauthenticated users. The `http403EntryPoint` will just return immediately with a 403 code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I changed my approach a little bit and followed your advises. I am just testing this out now so i am not authenticating the token, just getting the thing to work. But after my edit, the pre-auth version of my login works, but my form login approach always just returns authentication failure, anything wrong you can see in my edited code kind sir?

Comment: Again "just returns authentication failure" doesn't really describe the problem very well. Do some debugging - describe what you do, what requests are sent and what responses the server sends. Look in the debug log and see why it says authentication is failing. The debug output provides a very detailed account of how each request is handled.

Comment: Dont know how to get the debug output. But what I do know is that if I put " <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" />" inside the authentication manager where myUserDetailsService is then the form login works but if i have it like it is, then the token login works.

Comment: It worked now when <authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider" /> was behind the other authentication provider in the authentication manager. Thanks for the help Luke.